# Automating search through Google

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get my windows forms to load google.dk into my webBrowser element, then fill in "Frederik", and press Search.

I've tied the fill + search action to a single button, and here is what happens: On the first click, it types in "Frederik" in the search field, but then I have to press once again for it to actually search. I want it to be one action through one button, not pressing the same button twice (and I don't understand why it requires two clicks either, which concerns me.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.dk");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Search();

        while (webBrowser1.IsBusy)
        {
        }

        Submit();
    }

    private void Search()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").InnerText = "Frederik";
    }

    private void Submit()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnK").InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: It seems to be some problem with my Search function not being done, before my Submit function is used  - if I put a timer on, when using Search, and then letting Submit be used when the timer is at 5 seconds, it works perfectly in one click. Is there any way to check whether my Search function is done, as using a timer feels sloppy?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your manipulations you could do this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.dk/search?q=Frederik");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I forgot to mention that this is just practice for filling out a full form an another website, so that wont cut it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `q` paramter  and set it to your search string.
If you already knew that and you want to mimick user input and press the search button you can try the following:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "document.getElementsByName(\"btnK\")[0].click()"});
```

Remove the while loop inside the button click and handle `BrowserDocumentCompleted`.
You don't need to set up a timer nor split the search and submit functions.
Webbrowser functions that you are using to manipulate the document are not async and will be executed consecutively.

You code should look something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static bool _isDocumentLoaded;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _isDocumentLoaded = false;
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
        webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
    }

    private void WebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            return;

        _isDocumentLoaded = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Webpage loaded successfully");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isDocumentLoaded)
        {
            FillDocumentForms();
            Submit();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Webpage is currently loading");
        }
    }

    private void FillDocumentForms()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document?.InvokeScript("eval",
            new object[] {"document.getElementById(\"lst-ib\").innerText = \"Frederik\""});
    }

    private void Submit()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document?.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "document.getElementsByName(\"btnK\")[0].click()" });
    }
}
```

Comment: The same thing happens unfortunately - first time I click the button, "Frederik" appears, but then I have to click once more for the search to happen.

Comment: I tried that as well. The only thing that currently makes it work in one button click, is using a timer, that then calls my submit function after 5 seconds.